# How can I map one object usage to route to 2 objects?

Tags: javascript, call

I use totango for some usage tracking. Now, while we try to rework the way we track, I want to send trackings into 2 different totango accounts, for a transition period.

I've managed to split the objects into `window.totango_old` and `window.totango_beta`.

Now instead of replacing all the old usages of `window.totango`, I was wondering whether I can make window.totango simply apply any arbitrary method I use on it onto the 2 different objects specified above.

I've tried figuring out the usage with `.apply()`, but I can't fully grasp how it would work in my case.

I want to avoid doing this:

```
window.totango = function() {
    return {
        track: function(event, value) {
            window.totango_old.track(event, value);
            window.totango_beta.track(event, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Because it means I have to map the usable functions one by one. Is there a "catch-all" way that would pass any method I call on an object, and let me get its name and arguments, to pass on to different objects dynamically?

I tried running a test, like so:

```
window.test2 = function() {
    return {
        testFunc: function(a, b) {
            console.log([a, b]);
        }
    }
};

window.test = function() {
    this.apply(window.test2, arguments)
    // also tried: window.test2.apply(window.test2, arguments)
};

window.test.testFunc("1", "2");
```

But I received the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: how many of these totango methods would you actually need to wrap?  It may be tedious, but for now it's probably the best solution.

Comment: just 2, which will later reduce to 1, but i have a whole lot of events to update so I would rather avoid changing the way the function is called for tracking

Comment: To fix your original test, I think you just need to immediately invoke that anonymous function, i.e. `window.totango = (function() { return { ... } })();`.  The problem you have at the moment is that `window.totango` is just a function that hasn't been invoked and has no properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
window.callFunction = function( method, args ) {
    var res = { };

    //Set the default values
    method = method || 'track';
    args = args || [ ]; 

    //in case we want the result of the functions
    res.old = window.totango_old[ method ].apply( window.totango_old, args );
    res.beta = window.totango_beta[ method ].apply( window.totango_beta, args );

    return res;
}
```

Because totango_old is an object, you can use the name of the method as the index, then call apply on the returned function and pass your arguments. The first parameter of apply is the value of "this" in that context. Depending on how the module is set up it is important to have the right value in the first parameter. The second parameter passed to apply is the arguments to pass to the function.

You could possibly do something like this

```
function TotangoFill () {

}
TotangoFill.prototype = {
    callFunction: function ( method, args ) {
        var res = { };

        //Set the default values
        args = args || [ ]; 

        //in case we want the result of the functions
        res.old = window.totango_old[ method ].apply( window.totango_old, args );
        res.beta = window.totango_beta[ method ].apply( window.totango_beta, args );

        return res;
    },
    track: function( event, value ) {
        // arguments is an array of all the arguments passed to this function
        return this.callFunction( 'track', arguments );
    },
    anotherMethod: function( ) {
        //You don't need to define the parameters, just pass them on 
        return this.callFunction( 'anotherMethod', arguments );
    },
    customEvent: function( value ) {
        //Add another layer of abstraction
        return this.track( 'customEvent', value );
    }
}

window.totango = new TotangoFill( )
```

Comment: Right now they're being called like so: `totango.track('event', 'value')`, I'm assuming I would have to modify it to `totango('track', 'event', 'value')` for this method to work?

Comment: Thank you :) looks like I still have to fill in the names for the available functions, but it beats my original solution.

Comment: @ChenAsraf IMHO, if you've only got two methods this is unnecessarily complicated.  It also changes the return value (although that may not matter)

Comment: @Alnitak, you may be right, however you could easily add shortcut methods to this as well. See edit

Comment: Thank you both. I've just added the filler methods without arguments and passed the `arguments` variable, I was just hoping to discover a future-proof method as well :) I just wish there was a JS equivalent to PHP's `__call()` ;)

Comment: @ChenAsraf in ES6 there's the new `Proxy` object that allows you to intercept function calls (and other object property accesses)

Comment: It will be soon https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: That's awesome, but it'll probably be a problem for older browsers for a while won't it? Once it's implemented

Comment: @ChenAsraf yeah, it'll be a problem, hence why I didn't suggest it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your attempt to wrap `totango` which explains the error in your test, and can be easily resolved without changing your invocations.

Specifically, you need to actually invoke the function that you assigned to `window.totango` such that `totango` contains the *returned object*, and not the function itself, i.e.:

```
window.totango = (function() {
    return {
        track: function(event, value) {
            window.totango_old.track(event, value);
            return window.totango_beta.track(event, value);
        }
    }
})();  // invocation
```